# goto unexpected with blank choice

Tags: batch-file, cmd, goto

My problem:
I set a VAR with prompt and three IF to let choice.
Fourth choice doesn't work. I would like that if i push enter without type anything, it goes back to :MOSTRA.
Actually leaving it blank and typing enter on the keyboard it give back GOTO WAS UNEXPECTED and close CMD.
Where am i wrong?

```
:MOSTRA
ECHO Make your choice.
ECHO.
ECHO A) Ok
ECHO B) Ko
ECHO Esci
SET /P choose=Scelta: 
if /I %choose%==A GOTO OK
if /I %choose%==B GOTO KO
if /I %choose%==esci GOTO FINE
if /I %choose%=="" GOTO ERROR


:ERROR
ECHO You type nothing.
ECHO.
GOTO MOSTRA

:KO
ECHO Bad choice
ECHO.
GOTO MOSTRA

:OK
ECHO Right choice
ECHO.
GOTO MOSTRA

:FINE
exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET /P choose=Scelta: 
if /I "%choose%"=="A" GOTO OK
if /I "%choose%"=="B" GOTO KO
if /I "%choose%"=="esci" GOTO FINE
if /I "%choose%"=="" GOTO ERROR
```

CMD will substitute the value of `choose` in the place of `%choose%` so

```
if /I %choose%==A GOTO OK
```

is interpreted as

```
if /I ==A GOTO OK
```

which generates the error.

There is a more subtle error, too.

If you first choose `a` or `b`, you get the "right choice" or "bad choice" response, correctly BUT if your next choice is simply `ENTER` the response doesn't change - the previous response will be repeated.

The reason is that `set /p` does not change `choose` if you simply type `ENTER`. What you need is

```
SET "choose="
SET /P choose=Scelta: 
if /I "%choose%"=="A" GOTO OK
```

which sets `choose` to [nothing]

Comment: very nice explanation. thank you for the SET "choose=" advice too.