# Using GOTO inside an IF statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, goto

```
   if  %_var%==1 (
    goto :group1
) else if  %_var%==2 (
    goto :group2
) else (
    goto :groupOthr
)
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I keep getting the error -

> *( was unexpected at this time.*

Tried doing this -

```
   if  %_var%==1 (goto :group1
) else if  %_var%==2 (goto :group2
) else (goto :groupOthr
)
```

And then I get -

> (goto was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [goto unexpected with blank choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025303/goto-unexpected-with-blank-choice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if  "%_var%"=="1" (
    goto :group1
) else if  "%_var%"=="2" (
    goto :group2
) else (
    goto :groupOthr
)
```

Just got it right. Found the answer here - [goto unexpected with blank choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025303/goto-unexpected-with-blank-choice?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Simplify like this. And if you have your 'groupOthr' code directly below this you can remove the last goto.

```
if  "%_var%"=="1" goto :group1
if  "%_var%"=="2" goto :group2
goto :groupOthr
```

Also note that I quoted both sides of the comparison to avoid a problem if the variable is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure you should have been using.

```
if "%_var%"=="1" (
    goto :group1
) else (
    if "%_var%"=="2" (
        goto :group2
    ) else (
        goto :groupOthr
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need any brackets, they cause errors alot in if statements.
here is an example of a working if statement without brackets:

```
@echo off
:Main
cls
echo Press 1 or 2!
choice /c 12 /N >nul
if errorlevel 2
goto :Option2
if errorlevel 1
goto :Option1
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:Option2
cls
echo You pressed the number 2!
pause >nul
goto :Main
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:Option1
cls
echo You pressed the number 1!
pause >nul
goto :Main
```

Comment: Brackets (or parentheses) are perfectly fine, they do not cause problems when used correctly and are mandatory together with `else` clauses...

Comment: No I mean If you don't use them right. I know you need them in else clauses but the user put the bracket like this:    (goto

Comment: The OP uses them right (althouth their second attempt looks odd, but it is not wrong)...

Comment: Sorry I said that wrong. Meant to say if they use them with the incorrect structure if you know what I mean. Because of their previous commands, windows thought the ( was part of another command.

Answer (score 0):

```
if %_var%==1 ( goto group1)
if %_var%==2 ( goto group2)
goto groupothr
```

put the spacebar in before goto... also try one after...

i don't see how my original answer didn't work... the following code is in one of my batch files, and it works fine:

```
if not defined targeturl (goto err400)
```

but, it also works like `if not defined targeturl ( goto err400 )`

also, i have a script:

`@echo off
set defini=hi
if "%defini%"=="hi" (goto tyr)
echo no go.
pause
exit
:tyr
echo goto worked!
pause
exit`

which also works like:

`@echo off
set defini=hi
if "%defini%"=="hi" ( goto tyr)
echo no go.
pause
exit
:tyr
echo goto worked!
pause
exit`

try copying the above code and saving it to trygoto.bat, and run it.

Answer (score -1):

if %_var%==1 (goto group1)

if %_var%==2 (goto group2)

goto groupothr

try that! upvote if it worked!